Password in PostgreSQL necessary?
It seems like I can access the postgres user with any arbitrary password or even with none when opening pgAdmin4. ChatGPT tells me that this is the case if pg_hba.conf has the line:
local   all             postgres                                trust
And indeed I needed to change that in order to make PostgreSQL even working on my macbook according to some posts here on stackoverflow. Now people recommend to change that back to "md5" instead of "trust" and set a password. Will it still work when I reset it? Or is it even necessary to reset it if I am the only one who knows the password to the machine?

What do you mean with "works"? You should get a clear view what you want and then set up your authentication accordingly. trust works, it's just insecure, as you trust everyone that can reach your database.

Will it still work when I reset it? yes it will work, but as you setup password to the postgres user , you will have to remember it and store it somewhere safe. This is the best practice but hope you got what you need to trade.
Or is it even necessary to reset it if I am the only one who knows the password to the machine? it depends do you want to take over head of remembering the password? because you definately need to once you set it up, as you are only one to use your machine its not mandatroy to reset but its just a best practice. you need to choose according to your need.

You could try to read the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/client-authentication.html


If you are going to use password authentication use scram-sha-256 instead of md5, it is more secure and available on all currently supported Postgres versions. 2) local means socket connections only, which means the connecting client has to be on your machine. At that point it is possible that whoever/whatever has access could also have the privileges to reset/create a line in pg_hba.conf to trust anyway. It comes down to what your larger security setup is and your failure tolerance is.


"And indeed I needed to change that"  You chose to change that.  Surely there were other options.


And indeed I needed to change that in order to make PostgreSQL even working on my macbook according to some posts here on stackoverflow.

That's not the case. trust is the easiest one, but other auth mechanisms work, too.
Here is an overview over PostgreSQLs authentication methods.
For local connections on the same system I would choose peer authentication, which relies on your user and doesn't need a password. With this method, you don't open your DB up to everyone (system users, other users), but still don't need a password to choose, remember or type in everytime.

This answer needs work. 1) Peer depends on you being logged in to the OS as that user, so you probably need to remember a password or some other OS auth method to do that. 2) Peer doe snot work on Windows

@Adrian: 1) It's possible to map between system usernames and DB usernames, if you read the linked doc of peer. The PostgreSQL client always runs as some system user. 2) In the question he's talking about macOS. Well, it's not 100% clear, but I read the question like he wants to setup a local DB connection.

You still have to log in as the OS username before the mapping to the Postgres username can happen.
